zio-http and Tapir: provide layers globally
Hello I'm starting a project with ZIO, zio-http, Tapir and Scala 3, I'm configuring ZLayers:
my routes:
object DeckRoute:

  val deckRoutes: List[ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any]] =
    List(
      listRoute(),
      findByIdRoute(),
      insertRoute(),
      updateRoute(),
      deleteRoute()
    )

  private def listRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def listRouteLogic() =
      ListDeck
        .list()
        .mapBoth(
          _ => DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()),
          d => d.map(_.into[DeckListResponse].transform)
        )
        .either
        .provideLayer(appEnvironment)

    DeckEndpoint.listEndpoint.serverLogic(_ => listRouteLogic())

  private def findByIdRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def findByIdRouteLogic(id: Long) =
      FindByIdDeck
        .findById(id)
        .mapBoth(
          _ => DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()),
          _.into[DeckDetailsResponse].transform
        )
        .either
        .provideLayer(appEnvironment)

    DeckEndpoint.findByIdEndpoint.serverLogic(p => findByIdRouteLogic(p))

  private def insertRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def insertRouteLogic(request: DeckInsertRequest) =
      InsertDeck
        .insert(request.into[InsertDeckDomain].transform)
        .mapBoth(
          _ => DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()),
          _.into[DeckInsertedResponse].transform
        )
        .either
        .provideLayer(appEnvironment)

    DeckEndpoint.insertEndpoint.serverLogic(p => insertRouteLogic(p))

  private def updateRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def updateRouteLogic(id: Long, request: DeckUpdateRequest) =
      UpdateDeck
        .update(
          request.into[UpdateDeckDomain].withFieldConst(_.id, id).transform
        )
        .mapBoth(
          _ => DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()),
          _.into[DeckUpdatedResponse].transform
        )
        .either
        .provideLayer(appEnvironment)

    DeckEndpoint.updateEndpoint.serverLogic(p => updateRouteLogic(p._1, p._2))

  private def deleteRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def deleteRouteLogic(id: Long) =
      DeleteDeck
        .delete(id)
        .orElseFail(DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()))
        .either
        .provideLayer(appEnvironment)

    DeckEndpoint.deleteEndpoint.serverLogic(p => deleteRouteLogic(p))

my layers config
object Environment:

  type AppType = ListDeck & FindByIdDeck & InsertDeck & UpdateDeck & DeleteDeck

  val appEnvironment: ZLayer[Any, Nothing, AppType] =
    ZLayer.make[AppType](DeckService.layer, DeckQueryService.layer)

my main class
object App extends ZIOAppDefault:

  private val routes: Routes[Any, Response] =
    ZioHttpInterpreter().toHttp(swaggerEndpoints ++ deckRoutes)

  val run: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Nothing] = Server
    .serve(routes)
    .provide(
      ZLayer.succeed(Server.Config.default.port(8080)),
      Server.live
    )

Im my DeckRoutes I defined for each route .provideLayer(appEnvironment). I wanted do use a global config to define my layers insteade of set for each endpoint, it's possible ?
my dependencies:
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "3.3.4"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "br.com.flashcards"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "zio-flashcards"

val tapirVersion = "1.11.9"
val zioVersion = "2.1.13"
val circeVersion = "0.14.10"
val catsVersion = "2.12.0"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "zio-flashcards",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "dev.zio" %% "zio" % zioVersion,
      "dev.zio" %% "zio-http" % "3.0.1",
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-zio" % tapirVersion,
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-zio-http-server" % tapirVersion,
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-swagger-ui-bundle" % tapirVersion,
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-json-circe" % tapirVersion,
      "com.softwaremill.sttp.tapir" %% "tapir-enumeratum" % tapirVersion,
      "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % circeVersion,
      "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % circeVersion,
      "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % circeVersion,
      "io.scalaland" %% "chimney" % "1.5.0",
      "dev.zio" %% "zio-test" % zioVersion % Test
    ),
    testFrameworks += new TestFramework("zio.test.sbt.ZTestFramework")
  )


I haven't used Tapir with Play but from the documentation I see that there's a zServerLogic that may be what you're looking for so that you don't have to provide layers when building routes. See https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/stable/server/ziohttp.html#server-logic

I think the repo softwaremill - realworld-tapir-zio might help you.

I think this example might be relevant? https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/sttp/tapir/examples/ZioEnvExampleHttp4sServer.scala

Basically you'd need a ZServerEndpoint[DeckServicy, Any] etc.

I refactored my code using a project shared by @GastónSchabas,  which solved my problem, thank you :)

@JoseLuizJunior that's awesome. Is it possible, try to add an answer detailing what you did or how you solve your issue

To solve my problem I follow a example shared by @Gastón Schabas, I transformed my route object in a Class, create a ZLayer and insert it in a ZIO provide in a Main class :
package br.com.flashcards

import br.com.flashcards.adapter.endpoint.DeckEndpoint
import br.com.flashcards.config.EndpointConfig
import br.com.flashcards.core.service.impl.DeckService
import br.com.flashcards.core.service.query.impl.DeckQueryService
import sttp.tapir.server.interceptor.cors.CORSConfig.AllowedOrigin
import sttp.tapir.server.interceptor.cors.{CORSConfig, CORSInterceptor}
import sttp.tapir.server.ziohttp.{ZioHttpInterpreter, ZioHttpServerOptions}
import zio.*
import zio.http.*

object App extends ZIOAppDefault:

  override def run: ZIO[Any with ZIOAppArgs with Scope, Any, Any] =
    val options: ZioHttpServerOptions[Any] =
      ZioHttpServerOptions.customiseInterceptors
        .corsInterceptor(
          CORSInterceptor.customOrThrow(
            CORSConfig.default.copy(
              allowedOrigin = AllowedOrigin.All
            )
          )
        )
        .options

    (for {
      endpoints <- ZIO.service[EndpointConfig]
      httpApp = ZioHttpInterpreter(options).toHttp(endpoints.endpoints)
      actualPort <- Server.install(httpApp)
      _ <- Console.printLine(s"Application zio-flashcards started")
      _ <- Console.printLine(
        s"Go to http://localhost:8080/docs to open SwaggerUI"
      )
      _ <- ZIO.never
    } yield ())
      .provide(
        EndpointConfig.layer,
        DeckRoute.layer,
        DeckService.layer,
        DeckQueryService.layer,
        Server.defaultWithPort(8080)
      )
      .exitCode


my route. Obs: I refactored my traits with insert, update, delete and find in two traits, Read and Write Traits
package br.com.flashcards.adapter.endpoint

import br.com.flashcards.adapter.endpoint.doc.DeckDocEndpoint
import br.com.flashcards.adapter.endpoint.request.{
  DeckInsertRequest,
  DeckUpdateRequest
}
import br.com.flashcards.adapter.endpoint.response.error.DeckError
import br.com.flashcards.adapter.endpoint.response.{
  DeckDetailsResponse,
  DeckInsertedResponse,
  DeckListResponse,
  DeckUpdatedResponse
}
import br.com.flashcards.core.exception.DeckException
import br.com.flashcards.core.service.query.DeckRead
import br.com.flashcards.core.service.{
  DeckWrite,
  InsertDeckDomain,
  UpdateDeckDomain
}
import io.scalaland.chimney.dsl.*
import sttp.tapir.ztapir.*
import zio.*

import java.time.OffsetDateTime

case class DeckEndpoint(
    write: DeckWrite,
    read: DeckRead
):

  val endpoints: List[ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any]] =
    List(
      listRoute(),
      findByIdRoute(),
      insertRoute(),
      updateRoute(),
      deleteRoute()
    )

  private def listRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def listRouteLogic() =
      read
        .list()
        .mapBoth(
          _ => DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()),
          d => d.map(_.into[DeckListResponse].transform)
        )

    DeckDocEndpoint.listEndpoint.zServerLogic(_ => listRouteLogic())

  private def findByIdRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def findByIdRouteLogic(
        id: Long
    ) =
      read
        .findById(id)
        .mapBoth(
          _ => DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()),
          _.into[DeckDetailsResponse].transform
        )

    DeckDocEndpoint.findByIdEndpoint.zServerLogic(p => findByIdRouteLogic(p))

  private def insertRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def insertRouteLogic(
        request: DeckInsertRequest
    ) =
      write
        .insert(request.into[InsertDeckDomain].transform)
        .mapBoth(
          _ => DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()),
          _.into[DeckInsertedResponse].transform
        )

    DeckDocEndpoint.insertEndpoint.zServerLogic(p => insertRouteLogic(p))

  private def updateRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def updateRouteLogic(
        id: Long,
        request: DeckUpdateRequest
    ) =
      write
        .update(
          request.into[UpdateDeckDomain].withFieldConst(_.id, id).transform
        )
        .mapBoth(
          _ => DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()),
          _.into[DeckUpdatedResponse].transform
        )

    DeckDocEndpoint.updateEndpoint.zServerLogic(p =>
      updateRouteLogic(p._1, p._2)
    )

  private def deleteRoute(): ZServerEndpoint[Any, Any] =
    def deleteRouteLogic(
        id: Long
    ) =
      write
        .delete(id)
        .orElseFail(DeckError.GenericError("", "", 500, OffsetDateTime.now()))

    DeckDocEndpoint.deleteEndpoint.zServerLogic(p => deleteRouteLogic(p))

object DeckRoute:

  val layer: ZLayer[
    DeckWrite & DeckRead,
    DeckException,
    DeckRoute
  ] = ZLayer.fromFunction(DeckEndpoint(_, _))


Thank you :)
